# Cordova: Statusbar text on iOS disappearing

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I'm building an app on iOS and Android using Cordova 4.1.2 and the org.apache.cordova.statusbar plugin (version 0.1.8).

On iOS 8 (simulator and several different devices) the content of the status bar keep disappearing. Sometimes it stays visible for a while after the app launches but mostly it disappears very soon after launch.

The bar itself is still there but I can't do anything with it. Things like `StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#FF0000")` or the other styling methods have no effect. The bar always keeps the background color that I defined in my config.xml and it shows no content (no carrier, no battery status, nothing), it's just a solid strip of color.

When I call `StatusBar.isVisible` it returns `false` although the bar is obviously visible. When I then call `StatusBar.show()`, it disappears completely.

If I try removing the statusbar plugin, the bar completely disappears already during the splash screen.

I want to have a white status bar with black text on it. When my app shows the splash screen, the bar still looks like I want it to but then becomes empty. What can I do about this?

---

**Update:** I now removed the plugin completely, ran `platforms/ios/cordova/clean` and then compiled everything again. Now the statusbar usually stays visible for a bit longer and looks correct at first but still disappears a few seconds (about 10s) after the app has launched.

Comment: Are you calling `StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#FF0000")` after the deviceReady event? Wouldn't clarify the very weird behavior you are seeing though..

Comment: Strange that you're not even getting the battery status. Per this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227141/cordova-statusbar-black-on-black-on-ios), you may want to try setting the colors in the config.xml instead:
`<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#FFFFFF" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="darkcontent" />`